# Dynamically hide/show header in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) for routing purpose. I want to dynamically hide or show header on one component. Any way to do it?

I change headerLeft dynamically like this but can not find any way to do it for entire header.

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerRight: navigation.state.params ? navigation.state.params.headerRight : null
});

this.props.navigation.setParams({
        headerRight: (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => blaa} >
                     <Text>Start</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
});
```

I want something like this - hide/show header based on state:

```js
this.props.navigation.setParams({
        header: this.state.header
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it working:

Don't know why it is so but passing `undefined` to header will show default header and `null` will hide the header.

I am doing something like this:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: navigation.state.params ? navigation.state.params.header : undefined
});
```

and on state change;

```js
this.props.navigation.setParams({ 
        header: null 
});
```

Comment: @kaya null hides the header. that is fine. what I dint get is how header is resetting to original on setting it undefined dynamically.

Comment: I didn't find it in docs but I can say that undefined means not defined so it resets the value.

Comment: @kaya Yes that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack), setting the `header` to null hides the header. Go about it like this

```js
this.props.navigation.setParams({
  header: this.state.header ? whatever-you-want : null
})
```

Comment: Hiding it is easy with null but what should be the value for 'whatever-you-want'

Comment: you said you wanted to dynamically hide or show the header component right? whatever-you-want should be substituted for a react element or function. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#header that you want to be shown as the header

Comment: here header is not separate react element, header is a part of react-navigation library.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setParams` as stated by other answers, you can use `setOptions` directly. Something like:

```js
navigation.setOptions({ headerShown: false })
```

You can take navigation from the route props or using the `useNavigation` [hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/)

This way you don't need to add logic to your route, but apply the effect directly

Answer (score 0):

I need to set both of `headerShow` and `header` options:

on fullscreen

```
navigation.setOptions({ headerShown: false, header: null });
```

on exist fullscreen

```
navigation.setOptions({ headerShown: true, header: undefined });
```