# Hide and show reactnavigation headers onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) and want to Hide/Show the header onScroll or onPress. Is this pseudo code the proper way to go about it? Also, could you please advice on what props do I need to pass and how do I pass them from the `_handleHide` and `_handleShow` functions?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native'

class MyApp extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'MyTitle'         // this is the header I want to hide/show
    }

    constructor () {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          showHeader: false
        }
        this._handleHide = this._handleHide.bind(this);
        this._handleShow = this._handleShow.bind(this);
    }

    _handleHide(){
        // how do i code this to hide the header?
    }
    _handleShow(){
        // how do i code this to show the header?
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button onPress={this._handleHide} title="Hide Header" />
            <Button onPress={this._handleShow} title="Show Header" />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'
    }});

export default MyApp;
```

Many thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

```
_handleHide(){
    this.setState({showHeader: false});
}

_handleShow(){
    this.setState({showHeader: true});
}
```

Comment: Your answer should lie somewhere in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776798/dynamically-hide-show-header-in-react-native?rq=1

Comment: @ReyHaynes Thanks .. What is on State change in that post? Is that the function body? Does state change mean the function called on `onPress`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no on state change for that post I mentioned. Not near a computer right now but I would add a state in the constructor called `showHeader: true` and in `_handleHide` and `_handleShow`, change the state of showHeader.

Then from the post [Dynamically hide/show header in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776798/dynamically-hide-show-header-in-react-native?rq=1):

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
  header: this.state.showHeader ? whatever-you-want : null
})
```

Comment: Sorry for this sir .. but where am I calling `this.props.navigation.setParams`? I think I'm able to understand the logic here. I updated my question with the 2 functions body in *Update1* Please Help

Comment: Am I calling it in `componentDidMount`? Tried that not working :(

Comment: If I put `this.props.navigation.setParams({` under static navigationOptions, I'm getting error. Where do I set the params from?