# Hide and show navigation header on react native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'll like to hide the navigation header when clicked on the icon, the code bellow hides the header but do not restore it when search back button is pressed ....

Here is the code:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const {params} = navigation.state;

    return {
            title: 'Chats',
            titleStyle: {
                color: '#ffffff',  
            },
            tintColor: '#ffffff',
            headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "#E6A919"
            },
            header: navigation.state.params ? navigation.state.params.header : undefined, 
            headerTitleStyle: {
                color: '#ffffff'
            }, 
            headerRight: () =>     
                                  <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={
                                        () => {
                                            
                                            navigation.setParams({ header: null });
                                            navigation.setParams({ showSearch: true });
                                        }   
                                    }                             
                                  >
                                    <Icon
                                        style={{ width: 24, height: 24, margin: 15, color: '#ffffff', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                                        name={"search"}
                                    />
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
    }        
}

onBackPressed = () => {
    console.log("Back pressed!");
    
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ showSearch: false });
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ header: true });
    this.resetSearchText();
};
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776798/dynamically-hide-show-header-in-react-native) answers your question.
You're doing right, you just need to add the conditional expression now to return the header only when the `navigation.state.params.header` is different of undefined.

Comment: Thanks! worked to hide the header... but how do I restore it when pressing back button?  Code has been modified on the question....

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

To make it visible again I solved setting 'undefined' to header...